# Convert query to a Left-Join (?) to include userid's without a match

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying use a MySQL query to build a leaderboard of users in a game of Bowl Mania (where users each try to predict the winner of each College Football game, and assign a points weighting to each selection).

I have 3 tables:

```
--games
id   team1   team2   year

--picks
userid  gameid  points

--actResults
gameid   winner
```

I would like to build a SELECT query that orders each user based on the summer of their "Points" wager for each successfully predicted game (i.e. a successful wager of 5 on gameid=1 earns 5 points, while unsuccessful predictions earn 0).

The query below almost accomplishes what I want, but the only problem is that it does not include users who have zero points (i.e. users who do not have any matches between picks.winners and actResults.winners).

```
SELECT DISTINCT picks.userid AS Player, SUM( picks.points ) AS Points
FROM picks, games, actResults
WHERE picks.gameid = games.id
AND picks.winner = actResults.winner
AND games.year =  '2014'
AND picks.userid = picks.userid
GROUP BY picks.userid
ORDER BY Points DESC
```

Desired results would look something like this

```
Player  Points
User1   10
User4   9
User3   4
User2   0
User5   0
```

Comment: The `AND picks.userid = picks.userid` part of your query is a no-op, unless it can happen that `picks.userid` is ever null, in which case that part of your query is equivalent to `AND picks.userid IS NOT NULL`. Also -- unless `picks.winner`/`actResults.winner` contains much more detail than I expect, I think you need to add a few more conditions to restrict your `actResults`. Otherwise you're counting cases where the specified team won *any* game, rather than cases where they won the *specific* game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard part is not the conversion to `LEFT JOIN` (basically that just involves changing the comma-join to a regular ANSI `JOIN`, and then inserting the keyword `LEFT`), but rather, fixing the `SUM` expression to only add the rows where `actResults.winner = picks.winner`. Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT picks.userid AS Player,
       SUM(CASE WHEN actResults.winner IS NULL
                THEN 0
                ELSE picks.points
            END) AS Points
  FROM picks
  JOIN games
    ON games.id = picks.gameid
  LEFT
  JOIN actResults
    ON actResults.winner = picks.winner
 WHERE games.year = '2014'
 GROUP BY picks.userid
 ORDER BY Points DESC
;
```

(Another way is to skip the `LEFT JOIN` entirely, and use an `EXISTS` expression with a subquery.)

---

**Edited to add:** To add an "Available Points" field, as requested in the comments, you could write:

```
SELECT picks.userid AS Player,
       SUM(CASE WHEN actResults.winner = picks.winner
                THEN picks.points
                ELSE 0
            END) AS Points,
       SUM(CASE WHEN actResults.gameid IS NULL
                THEN picks.points
                ELSE 0
            END) AS AvailablePoints
  FROM picks
  JOIN games
    ON games.id = picks.gameid
  LEFT
  JOIN actResults
    ON actResults.gameid = games.id
 WHERE games.year = '2014'
 GROUP BY picks.userid
 ORDER BY Points DESC
;
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Didn't know about the CASE keyword. Thank you!

Comment: What if I wanted to add an additional (calculated) column to this query that would add up "Available Points"? It would be a sum of all the points a user has assigned to gameids which do not (yet) exist in the actResults table (i.e. those games have not been played yet)?

Comment: @RyanMiller: To answer that, I really need to see the corrected version of your current query. (Did you see my comment on your question?)

Comment: I'm using the exact query you posted. It works great. Luckily each team only plays a single game, so matching the "winner" between tables should work.

Comment: @RyanMiller: Oh, I see. O.K., I've added such a query to my answer.